# How to access a dynamically inserted table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My page has a table with two rows, like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-sm-8 room-status" data-roomstatusid="1" data-value="Active" data-edited="false">Active</td>
      <td class="col-sm-4"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt edit-status" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
        <div class="edit-controls hidden"><i class="fas fa-times-circle cancel-status-edit" style="margin-left: 5px;font-size: 20px;"></i><i class="fas fa-save save-status-edit" style="margin-left: 15px;font-size: 20px;"></i>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="status-template" class="hidden">
      <td class="col-sm-8 room-status" data-roomstatusid="-1" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td class="col-sm-4"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt edit-status hidden" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
        <div class="edit-controls" data-mode="new"><i class="fas fa-times-circle cancel-status-edit" style="margin-left: 5px;font-size: 20px;"></i><i class="fas fa-save save-status-edit" style="margin-left: 15px;font-size: 20px;"></i>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There is a button on the page that adds a row at the start of the table using the html of the hidden #status-template row.  All that works fine.

After the new row has been added, I can click the pencil icon on either it or what is now the second row (the one with "Active" in the first cell) and the javascript that detects the click works correctly.

If I click on the first `<td>` of the inserted row, the javascript that detects that click also works correctly, but if I click the first cell of what is now the second row (which contains "Active", the click is not detected.

My javascript is all delegated to the table element since I know there will be new elements added to the DOM.

The javascript to detect the click on the first `<td>` of a row looks like this

```
$('#room-status-table').on('click', 'tbody tr td:first', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('row-highlight')) {
    $(this).removeClass('row-highlight')
  } else {
    $('#room-status-table tbody tr').each(function() {
      $(this)
        .find('td:first')
        .removeClass('row-highlight')
    })
    $(this).addClass('row-highlight')
  }
})
```

The javascript to detect the click on the pencil icon is

```
$('#room-status-table').on('click', '.edit-status', function() {
  var cell = $(this).closest('tr').find('.room-status')
  $(cell).attr('contenteditable', 'true')
  $(cell).focus()
  $(this).addClass('hidden')
  $(this).next().removeClass('hidden')
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').addClass('row-highlight')
})
```

The code that creates the new row is

```
$("#new-status").on("click", function() {
  var html = "<tr>" + $("#status-template").html() + "</tr>"
  $("table > tbody > tr:first").before(html)
  $("table > tbody td:first").focus()
  $("#edit-room-submit").attr("disabled", "disabled")
})
```

Grateful for any help in figuring out why the click on the first `<td>` of the second `<tr>` is not triggering my click event.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the code that uses the template to create a new row?

Comment: Appended to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood the delegated selector `td:first`. What you will want to use is `td:first-child`.

While `:first` matches only a single element, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one i.e. one for each parent. This is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`.

Replace

```
.on('click', 'tbody tr td:first', ...)
```

with

```
.on('click', 'tbody tr td:first-child', ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just did this at my project. I can share like an example my code which trigger one click and doubleClick at table row added via ajax:

```
$('table tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('tr.selected-row')){
        $(this).parent('tbody').find('tr.selected-row, td.selected-row').removeClass('selected-row');
        $(this).addClass('selected-row').find('td').addClass('selected-row');
        if($(this).find("td a[title='View']").length > 0){
            var href = $(this).find("a[title='View']").attr("href");
            if(href) {
                window.location = href;
            }
        } else if($(this).find("td a[title='Update']").length > 0){
            var href = $(this).find("a[title='Update']").attr("href");
            if(href) {
                window.location = href;
            }
        }

    }

}).on('click', 'tr', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('tr.selected-row')){
        $(this).parent('tbody').find('tr.selected-row, td.selected-row').removeClass('selected-row');
        $(this).addClass('selected-row').find('td').addClass('selected-row');
    }
})
```